# displaying rows with not null columns excluded

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table named products with default NULL value for size, weight, dimensions
I need to fetch it to get rows with non NULL values the desired result would be like for first row
:

SKU name price size

1 ,product1 ,2.00 , 2

and the second row

SKU  name  price  weight

2 ,product2 ,3.00 , 3

I tried `COALESCE`  but I need also to get the corresponding column name for the non NULL value

```
SKU   name   price   size   weight    dimensions 

1   product1  2.00    2      NULL       NULL
2   product2  3.00    NULL   3          NULL
3   product3  4.00    NULL   NULL       2x11x22
```

Comment: Please (try to ) explain more about: "I tried COALESCE but I need also to get the corresponding column name for the non NULL value"   What did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT()` to combine the column name with the column value. If the value is `NULL`, the concatenation will also be `NULL`, and `CONCAT_WS()` will ignore that argument.

```
CONCAT_WS(', ',
    CONCAT('size = ', size),
    CONCAT('weight = ', weight),
    CONCAT('dimensions = ', dimensions)
) AS attributes
```

`CONCAT_WS()` will ignore any null values in the arguments, so you won't get `,,` in the result.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but i am using dynamic approach so i won't use any if-else or switch statement

Comment: You should be able to put this into the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't have the column names in it. Show what you really expect.

Comment: How are you displaying the results? If you're using a programming language, it can skip the null columns.

Comment: I realized that `if` isn't needed, and updated the answer.

Comment: so concat ignore the null values it seems like working solution thank you very much

Comment: i can do it with php but using mysql is faster

Comment: Any operation that involves NULL returns NULL, unless it has a specific exception, like COALESCE

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `COALESCE`.

COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```sql
SELECT
   SKU,
   name,
   price,
   COALESCE(size,weight,dimensions) as extraInfo
FROM mytable;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Aabeg1R0)

output:

| SKU | name | price | extraInfo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 2.00 | 2 |
| 2 | product2 | 3.00 | 3 |
| 3 | product3 | 4.00 | 2x11x22 |